# Selenium driver with VBA - select option in <input drop down

Tags: vba, selenium

I read all the relevant threads in the forum, to no avail. I try to select an option in a dropdown in this hTML code:

```
<input name="tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails" type="text" id="tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails" class="async_list" autocomplete="off" data-ajax-id="CustomFieldLookup" data-ajax-allow-query="True" data-ajax-param1="143" data-ajax-param2="" data-selected-value="Pending">
```

So far, I am able to extract the current value with either options:

```
driver.FindElementByName("tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails").value
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@name='tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails']").Attribute("data-selected-value")
```

For the input, I tried the following methods:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@name='tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails']").AsSelect.SelectByValue "Completed"
'That returns the error: "Unexpected TagName Error. Expected=select Got=input"
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@name='tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails']").SendKeys "Completed"
'This writes the value in the dropdown but it cannot be saved
```

Any idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sendkeys is working perhaps you may need to select the option from the dropdown in addition to typing it. I have run into scenarios where you need to select the option from the drop down after you have sent it. In a side note: I have noticed that having waits between inputs also helps.

**Example**

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@name='tv1ASSIGNMENT_CF!CF_TEXT035AssignmentDetails']").SendKeys "Completed"
driver.Wait (10)
driver.SendKeys keys.ArrowDown
driver.SendKeys keys.Enter
```

I have noticed that in some lists, you need to add a wild card in the send keys method to correctly retrieve the option and then do the selection.

Comment: Thank you Sgdva, that would be a good approach. However I am not too keen to use it because it requires the installation of the SeleniumWrapper, which requires admin rights in my company's environment. It is possible to get them, but then every user of the script will have to do so. Any other idea?

Comment: Your question asks for selenium, so I don't understand how that doesn't come to play now. As Off-topic per your question: I understand red tape in companies, but there is no other way to work with browsers (there used to be a way with IE but is way too deprecated, potential security risk and most companies are uninstalling IE). Selenium for VBA may not be that easy, but for example you could install Python (which could be more likely to be installed) and use xlwings

Comment: I had only placed the driver in the right folder without installing the wrapper, that's why. I thought it was cool to be able to dodge the request of admin rights, but I realize it has to be done. I installed it anyway now. And switching to Python is a good suggestion, I was also thinking it would be best, and now it seems even easier than bothering with Selenium. I am actually coming from IE automation, but eventually faced the problem you mention. It was easy to share the automations but was not as stable as Selenium so I am glad it happened.

Comment: Actually I was suggesting using [Selenium with python](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-python.html) and then connect it with [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/examples)